# Chromatic polynomial of a bipartite graph replaced by a new graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, chromatic-polynomial

Consider a semi-regular  bipartite graph $C$ consisting of two parts $A$ (having each vertex of degree $\Delta$) and $B$ (having each vertex of degree $2$). Let its chromatic polynomial be $C(x)$. Now, consider connecting each  of the vertices in the independent sets $A$ and $B$  such that the resulting subgraph $A'$ is $\Delta$ regular and the subgraph  $B'$ is $\beta$ regular. Also consider that the maximum of chromatic numbers of $A'$ and $B'$ is $\chi$ and the chromatic polynomials of $A'$ and $B'$ are $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ respectively. Then, what is the chromatic polynomial of the new  graph $A'\cup B'\cup C$ where $\cup$ denotes union of vertex and edge sets of the subgraphs.

I think it is of the form $r(x)A(x)B(x)$ where $r(x)$ has some relation with $C(x)$. Specifically, I think the chromatic number of the new graph would be at most $2$ more than $\chi$.

Note that the case when the bipartite graph is just a bridge (edge) reduces $r(x)$ to $\frac{x-1}{x}$ . This may be verified by the deletion-contraction principle. But, what if we have more than one connecting edge between $A$ and $B$. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Please clarify your terminology. You are calling $A$ and $B$ "components" (implying there are no edges between them) but also "independent sets" (implying there have no edges inside them). Are $A$ and $B$ the biparts of the graph? If so, then they are independent sets, so have chromatic number $1$. What do you then mean by "consider that the maximum of chromatic numbers of $A$ and $B$ is $\chi$". Also, if I understand your construction, then the blown-up graph is bipartite, so have chromatic number $2$.

Comment: @verret sorry, clarified the word. But, a downvote is unreasonable, I think?

Comment: Verrret's complaint is still valid.  What does "the chromatic polynomial of $A$" mean?  I don't understand your "blowing up" operation either. Much more precision is required.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay again edited. Is it clear now?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "the maximum of chromatic numbers of $A$ and $B$ is $\chi$". Aren't $A$ and $B$ independent sets? (Note that I said that already.)

Comment: @verret I mean the maximum of chromatic numbers of the blown up subgraphs formed from the vertices in $A$ and $B$, that is connecting all the vertices of hitherto independent sets $A$ and $B$ so as to form two new subgraphs

Comment: I still don't understand the blow-up operation. Vertices are being joined to what?

Comment: @verret Think of the vertices being replaced with a new graph with the same number of vertices; the vertices maintaining their previous adjacencies also.

Comment: @verret as an example, think of $A$ to consist of $6$ vertices and $B$  consisting of $6m$ vertices and degree of each vertex in $A$ being $m$ and each vertex in $B$ has degree $2$. Let the chromatic polynomial of this bipartite graph be $C(x)$. Now, I replace $A$ with a $6$-cycle and $B$ with a cubic graph on $6m$ vertices, each with chromatic polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$. I expect a simple relation between $C(x), A(x), B(x)$ and the chromatic polynomial of the new graph. Hope it is now clear?

Comment: Still no actual definition of blow-up, voted to close

Comment: @verret changed the terminology. I think it should be reasonable now

Comment: Both of your guesses are wrong. For the chromatic number, think about the case where $C$ is a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay But my question assumes $C$ to be a semi regular graph, hence excluding the case of regular and thus, complete bipartite graph

Comment: Complete bipartite graphs are semiregular.   $C=K_{2,\Delta}$ satisfies your criteria. Take several copies of it so that you have more freedom to add edges.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay but i still think the chromatic number wont exceed the maximum of chromatic numbers plus two. Could you please elaborate a little more?